# Using css modules, how can I use composes to include a list of variables for colors

Tags: css, reactjs, postcss, css-modules

I am using [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) and [post-css](https://github.com/postcss/postcss). I have added the [post-css-simple-vars](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars) plugin

**colors.css**

```
$orange:   #ff6600;
$blue:   #056ef0;
```

In my **button.css** file, how do I use composition so I can reuse variables in `colors.css`?

**button.css**

```
.button {
    composes: * from '../styles/colors.css';
    background-color: $orange;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach I have found so far is to export your variables as `@value`'s using the [postcss-modules-values](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules-values) plugin

**colors.css**

```
@value blue: #0c77f8;
@value red: #ff0000;
@value white: #fff;
```

**button.css**

```
@value colors: "./colors.css";
@value blue, white, red from colors;

.button {
  color: blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Check out [css-module-npm-boilerplate](https://github.com/StevenIseki/css-module-npm-boilerplate) for an example